# Why are there so many pots with daffodils in Finland in April?

Tags: local-customs, event-based-effects, finland

I just visited Finland (specifically Helsinki and Porvoo) and a lot of shops and houses have daffodils near their doors (or gates). Is there any significance to this?

For future readers, it's currently April.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Daffodils are in Northern Europe thought to be flowers related to Easter. As Easter is this week, that's probably the reason for the large amount of these flowers. The flower is often called 'pääsiäislilja', freely translated to 'Easter lily' in Finnish.

Answer (score 6):

Because late winter early spring is when they bloom.  And for many they are the sign that spring is here and winter's cold is winding down.